# How can I edit song metadata in Songbird for music streamed via daap/firefly?

Tags: music, media, songbird

I right click on a song, click View metadata, and it says at the top "Metadata for the selected item cannot be edited".  I am sharing via samba and have it set to allow anynomous access.  Does Songbird not allow this by default for music being streamed to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Samba to share files in a selected folder check the smb.conf definitions.

Go to "Share Definitions" and before [Printers] check the parameter "writable": if it's set to "no" you cannot edit any file into the shared folder...

Comment: I am using Samba and I found and uncommented the line you mention.  I also have a map to user = Bad User and a nobody user with blank pw and nobody group setup.  And i chown'd my media directory for that user/group.